# How do I send a two string Dictionary to a server?

Tags: c#, php, dictionary, unity-game-engine, server

I'm new to Unity (and c#, along with PHP) and have been tasked with getting some old c# and PHP code working. The code below is supposed to send the dictionary (formData) to the PHP server that then converts it to json. The code is below:

```
...
//This code runs for each file that is uploaded, the file is a list of strings and integers.
Dictionary<string, string> formData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] data = s.Split(';');
                    uploadResultText.setText(file.Name + ":" + data[0] + " " + data[0]);
                    if (data[1] == "") data[1] = " ";
                    formData[data[0]] = data[1];
                }
            }
UnityWebRequest uploadRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(serverBaseURL, formData);
currentUploadRequest = uploadRequest;
yield return uploadRequest.SendWebRequest();
...
```

If this code is working, how will I need to receive it server-side?

Comment: Is your PHP server up and running?

Comment: @MrMoonMan That seems irrelevant?

Comment: @MrMoonMan Other sections of the code are successfully able to download data from the server, so it must be running.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) suggest your data will be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content, so you should look up how to receive that in PHP. Perhaps PHP's [`$_POST` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a server side error, the code above should work.
The server was returning http error 500 because it was requesting data that did not exist (caused by switching names on the app side, but not the server side).
The server side code uses `$_POST` to reference the incoming data, and a sample can be seen below.

```
if (isSet($_POST["App"])) {
    $dataArray = array();
    foreach($expectedFormInputCommon as $input) {
        if (isSet($_POST[$input])) {
            if (seralizeString($_POST[$input]) !== false) {
                $dataArray[$input] = seralizeString($_POST[$input]);
            } else {
                http_response_code(400);
                exit;
                }
        } else {
            http_response_code(400);
            $_POST[$input] = "empty";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After you Yield Return you can access the result:

```
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
{
    // Error
}
else
{
    var result = UnityWebRequest.Result;
}
```

Comment: After implementing a slightly modified version of this, I am almost certain it is a server side error (It gave me "ProtocallError"). Thank you!

Comment: @Sammyhus I don't understand how you can consider this to be an answer to your question. Your question is essentially "How can I create PHP code to handle my request?" and this answer doesn't address that at all.

Comment: @Llama as I understood it, the Server is working as other people are using. However, if it is not the answer, I can explan on it and try to answer the issue differently.

Comment: OP's question basically said they need to send their data to a server that converts it to JSON, and then the actual question part was _"If this code is working, how will I need to receive it server-side?"_ which suggests _OP_ needs to write the server side code. I'm not saying your answer is necessarily wrong, but if your answer is correct then OP needs to fix their question.

Comment: @Llama Listen, as an Engineer you are a stellar one. You understand the question asked within the Criteria. Correct me of I am wrong OP, but you don't have permission to change the Code on the Server?

He needs to find out if his part of the code is working or not. To that I would suggest testing with POSTMAN but I don't think OP has that experience dealing with generic API concepts... That being said I am happy to hop into a call with OP and explain how it would work.

Comment: @Llama the server side code is written, but it isn't mine and isn't quite working. I've been using Azure for hosting and if you have any debugging tips it would really help. For some reason I can't seem to get "echo" or "print" to work.

Comment: @MrMoonMan I am able to change the server code, and I was mostly trying to figure out where the issue was happening. I've been using Microsoft Azure for hosting (recommended by the person who originally wrote the code) and have been having trouble debugging. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Llama I should clarify that I have no clue what I'm doing when it comes to PHP. I'm having issues knowing if the code has ran a part or not.